# Docker- How to save files locally when I run docker container using bind mount?

Tags: python, docker, automation, continuous-integration, backend

I'm using `Docker` to automate my backend work in `Python`. I have a file `backend.py`, which when executed, downloads `pdf` files and converts them into images.

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.6.3
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN apt-get install -y ghostscript libgs-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libmagickwand-dev imagemagick --fix-missing
RUN apt-get install -y libpng-dev zlib1g-dev libjpeg-dev

WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

ADD backend.py .
ADD Vera.ttf .

CMD [ "python", "backend.py" ]
```

What I want is when I run the `Dockerfile` using the command:

> docker run -d -it --name devtest-1 --mount type=bind,source=D:\projects\imageProject\public\assets,target=/app/data kidsuki-test3

I want the the `pdf` files and images to get stored in my local machine in the path: `"D:\projects\imageProject\public\assets"` and also get stored in the container in the path : `"/app/data"`

But for now, what I'm getting is, it copies the files in my `"D:\projects\imageProject\public\assets"` folder and stores it in `"/app/data"` in the docker container devtest-1

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That seems like the behavior I'd expect; if you write to either the host or container directory, it should be visible in both places.  When you run your script, are the resulting files visible on the host?  What behavior do you expect to see?

Comment: It worked, I had to make a couple of changes, I changed the target from '/app/data' to '/app' also moved my backendd.py to the 'public/assets' folder.